# Modifying Ruby Source - Cannot modify method

Tags: c, ruby

I am new to C, trying to learn more via the Ruby source code.

When I compile Ruby from source, it does not seem to be recognizing any changes I make to method definitions. However, if I add a new method, say to string, pointing at a modified method, the new method works as expected.

```
# string.c

static VALUE
rb_str_empty(VALUE str)
{
    return Qtrue;
}

...

rb_define_method(rb_cString, "empty?", rb_str_empty, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cString, "my_empty?", rb_str_empty, 0);
```

Then in the Ruby console, we see that the new method reflects the new definition, but the old method still works as if the method were unmodified.

```
$ irb
> "sdf".my_empty?
true
> "sdf".empty?
false
```

How is Ruby "protecting" the original method definition? How could I make my changes register?

Comment: Apart from being a very in-depth and totally correct explanation, the answer by @matt below illustrates the same property, where he shows that `"asdf".send(:empty?) # => true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of Ruby uses a virtual machine. When you run some Ruby code, it is first compiled into bytecode, and then this bytecode is executed by the virtual machine. The VM includes instructions for things like assigning variables, creating classes, defining methods and (importly for this situation) dispatching methods. However, for some commonly used methods there are also special optimised bytecode instructions that bypass the normal method dispatch procedure. [`empty?` is one such method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/insns.def#L2010-L2046).

You can examine the bytecode for a bit of Ruby code with [`RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-c-compile) (and [`disasm`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-c-disasm) to view). First a “normal” method dispatch (with the non-existent method `foo`):

```
> puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile('"asdf".foo').disasm
== disasm: #<ISeq:<compiled>@<compiled>>================================
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putstring        "asdf"
0004 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:foo, argc:0, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0007 leave
```

The `opt_send_without_block` is the method dispatch instruction, trying to call `foo` (`mid` is “method ID”).

Now with the optimised bytecode for `empty?`:

```
> puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile('"asdf".empty?').disasm
== disasm: #<ISeq:<compiled>@<compiled>>================================
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putstring        "asdf"
0004 opt_empty_p      <callinfo!mid:empty?, argc:0, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0007 leave
```

`opt_empty_p` is the specialised bytecode instruction for the `empty?` method.

If you compare the source for this instruction with the [source for the normal function implementing `String#empty?`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/string.c#L1607-L1613) (the function you changed) you can see that in the [case of the receiver being a String](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/insns.def#L2024-L2025) the instruction code duplicates the code of the function, bypassing that function altogether (in some cases these optimised instructions have a direct call to the implementing function, bypassing the method dispatch code but using the same implementation).

The instruction does include a check to make sure the method hasn’t been replaced in Ruby, but this obviously doesn’t include modifications to the C source like here.

I think you should get your modified version of the function if you use `send`, as this doesn’t compile to the optimised instruction:

```ruby
'asdf'.send :empty?
```

If you are setup to edit and recompile Ruby, you should also be able to alter the instruction itself in the file `insns.def`. This file is used to create the code for the instructions during the build process. It’s not C itself, but the contents of each instruction block are just plain C.

Comment: Thank you @matt. This is all a lot to learn. I had actually stumbled across `opt_empty_p` in my search, but didn't understand it. Thanks for the deep answer.